# Where can I find kitchen sinks with walls extending above the counter top?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-sink

Does anyone know how to find tall kitchen sinks? What I mean are like one that is deep but part of the walls are above the counter by multiple inches so that the depth is made up partly above the counter top. Or alternatively is there a way to make a more typical sink mount this way and not look really weird?

A [sink like this](https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/deervalley-ally-20-ceramic-rectangular-vessel-bathroom-sink-drll1067.html) above the counter but extends to a good depth below would be ideal.

Comment: I think the reason you are having trouble finding something of this sort *for a kitchen* is the way that kitchen sinks are used - whether for washing dishes or for food prep, there is huge benefit to being able to slide things right up to the edge of the sink for ease of use. You lose that ease of use if the edge is a wall that goes a few inches above the counter.

Comment: Best I can imagine is a farm sink with something (tile?) to pad the sides. Can I ask why you want this?

Comment: If you have a drying rack next to it, how is the water going to drain back to the sink ?  What material is your counter-top?

Comment: @RohitGupta: I've seen folks use a wire shelf above the sink as a drain rack, to save counter space. That might be a solution here.  Seems to be more common in the UK than US, perhaps because older sinks are still in use. ("In America, 200 years is a long time. In the UK, 200 miles is a long distance.")

Comment: I suspect to get (what we are speculating that) you want is to have something custom built.

Answer (score 1):

Your buzzword is 'farmhouse' for searching. 'Farmhouse ceramic sink' returns thousands of hits like these...

[image]

Usually they're built into units to keep the top just below the drainer, but if you're in control of the unit manufacture, you can set it any height you like.

There was mention in comments that these may or may not be fully glazed right the way round. Mine is, but I don't have sweeping knowledge of the entire market space, so it's probably worth asking the retailer.

Comment: I guess my experience differs, but it's limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your counter top correctly you can use almost *any* sink. Wrap the opening with a framed wall and apply tile or cultured stone, for example. Drop in the sink. Presto.

Think of it like a tiny built-in spa where the tub is deeper than the walls:

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maid2match.com.au%2Ffreestanding-bath-vs-built-in%2F&psig=AOvVaw2uuQlCgQL5rW1BfdSmouUe&ust=1700672531997000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBQQjhxqFwoTCIiAxfXJ1YIDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAc)</sub>